# ethernet ipv4 total length field does not match overall length of frame

Tags: networking, header, ethernet, ipv4

what will happen when Total Length field value in IPv4 header is smaller than length of ethernet frame? How will behave a device when receive that kind of frame? Device recognized frame as invalid due to inconsistency and rejected it?

Second situation, max ethernet frame length is 1518 bytes - what will happen when I extend this frame and add additional 2 bytes. Assuming that IPv4 total length match length of extended frame.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the Total Length field in an IPv4 header ***must*** be smaller than the frame length; anything else is a sign of corruption. The IPv4 packet is the payload of the frame, so the frame length is the total packet length plus the frame header and trailer.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But, if the value of the Total Length field in an IPv4 header is smaller than length of ipv4 header and ipv4 data together, what will happen? Not including ETH header.

Comment: First, you would need to get past the sender not doing that at all since it violates the standard. If it happens in transit, the CRC would probably be incorrect, and the packet is discarded. If you somehow manage to purposely create this situation, what happens will depend on the OS and drivers. This could cause a buffer-overflow, which would be considered an attack. Modern OSes and drivers will probably look for this exact situation and discard the packet.

Comment: Ok, It's clear now. So, if I want to extend my frame I have to modify both Total Length and Checksum. I've got last question:

max ETH frame length is 1518B but my max IP Total Length is 65535B. It's not clear for me how to create such packet which has more bytes in IP frame than in Ethernet (ETH contains IPv4 header and payload).

Comment: Ethernet is not the only layer-2 protocol over which IP may be transmitted. The point of the layers is that each layer is independent of the others. When IP and ethernet were being developed, neither was a sure thing. IP was originally used over WAN circuits, and it wasn't at all clear that either protocol would survive. IP can be used with just about any layer-2 protocol, and each have different maximum lengths. For instance Wi-Fi has a different maximum length than ethernet. Frame Relay can have much larger maximum frame sizes than either of those.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I appriciate your help.

The problem appeared when I try to expand my frame. I'm implemanting high speed AES encryption system for 10Gbps Ethernet IPv4. The payload that I use to encryption starts after ETH and IPv4 header (256 + 16b), and AES output is always 128b and always valid. When the frame in ETH IPv4 standard has maximum length I can't expand my frame (the last 16b from AES module would exceed max frame length). Maybe I try use for output frame different ethertype, for example Jumbo Frame. What you think about that?

Comment: Jumbo frames are valid if everything supports them. That is commonly used in data centers for server replication and such.

Comment: last short question: If I use Total Length field greater than IPv4 header + IPv4 data, how will behave a device when receive this kind of packet? Rejected it?

Comment: That depends on the layer-4 protocol. UDP has the equivalent of the Total Length field in its header, TCP, has a Data Offset field which points to the first data byte in its header, or, read another way, gives you the total header size. UDP should be OK, but TCP may read beyond its data into uninitialized memory. Some OSes and drivers may get heartburn over that, and it wouldn't match the Checksum field. Other layer-4 protocols do it differently. I'm not sure which layer-4 protocol you are using for encryption, but it would make sense to look at the layer-4 header for it.